# What happens to blocks in a deleted blockchain?

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain

A chain has blocks 0..n. simultaneously and topologically distant on the network, miner A adds block x as n+1 and miner B adds block y as n+1. Then miner A adds another block z as block n+2.

As I understand it, the longer block, containing blocks x and z as n+1 and n+2 will survive and the chain containing block y as n+1 will be deleted.

What happens to block y in the shorter chain that was a valid transaction? If its chain is deleted and it is not in the longer chain, is it lost? That doesn't make sense to me.

In a large, active network these asynchronous actions must always be happening, like routing in IP.

How is this handled?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 2):

This happens every day in the Bitcoin Network. The nodes will follow the longest valid chain. 
Even the miner who propossed the block y as n+1 will reorganize his chain if he received a longer valid chain than his.

To avoid the dangers of a chain reorganization most exchanges wait 3 or 4 blocks before accepting a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

As blockchain is dependable technology, if one of the blocks gets deleted then it may cause an issue with validation in ledger part, the entire upcoming chain becomes invalidated. its explained better in [IBM Hyperledger](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-ibm-blockchain-chaincode-development-using-golang/index.html) project docs